# Configuração adicional para fazer referencia a .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web.config

Hoje ao tentar publicar uma nova versão da minha aplicação, apareceu o seguinte erro:

> Error 26  Mixed mode assembly is built against version 'v2.0.50727' of
>   the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

Nunca antes me tinha aparecido este erro, como não adicionei dll's novas na aplicação, não estou a entender a origem do erro. No entanto já fiz várias pesquisas com possíveis soluções, mas na hora de complicar devolve sempre o mesmo erro.

Seguindo [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2455654/what-additional-configuration-is-necessary-to-reference-a-net-2-0-mixed-mode?answertab=votes#tab-top), já tentei adicionar

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
```

no meu *Web.config*, porém sempre com o mesmo erro.

Ou seguindo [esta solução](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425707/mixed-mode-assembly-is-built-against-version-v2-0-50727-of-the-runtime) entre as várias respostas, nunca consegui resolver o erro.

O que poderá ter originado o erro? Como o posso solucionar?

**EDIT**
Deparei-me que este erro ocorre quando adiciono um serviço externo a minha aplicação (Web Reference), e que sem o serviço não acontece este erro. Ao integrar o serviço na aplicação o Web.config é alterado, talvez seja daí o erro?

```
<sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="MvcTesteLayout.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>
...

<applicationSettings>
    <MvcTesteLayout.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="MvcTesteLayout_com_frotasoft_www_API" serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://www.frotasoft.com/FrotaSoftGeo/Services/API.asmx</value>
      </setting>
    </MvcTesteLayout.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
```

Comment: Já tentou colocar `<supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>`?

Comment: Sim, já tentei @viniciushana

Comment: Esse erro ocorre apenas na publicação ou aparece em desenvolvimento também?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez é só na publicação/correr em modo release. Estou a utilizar um serviço (Web Reference), e testei que ao fazer publicação da minha aplicação sem o serviço no projecto não dá erro, mas caso o adicione dá este erro.

Comment: @CesarMiguel Ocorre alguma transformação no Web.config no momento da publicação? Desconfio que esse Web.config não está indo com as configurações para o seu servidor.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, sim ocorre alterações. Mas não encontro nada relativo a v2.0.50727. Vou alterar a questão e colocar as alterações do web.config

Answer (score 1):

Experimente montar o `Web.config` com os dois *runtimes*:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727" />
  </startup>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Comment: já tinha experimentado e experimentei de novo adicionar os runtimes e não resolveu. Inclusive, nas propriedades do projeto também meti a Generate serialization assembly a OFF